# Перебор направлений в цикле и геокодирование

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос. У меня в базе храниться 1800 направлений (например Москва - Казань). Мне необходимо перебрать их все в цикле, геокодировать каждый населенный пункт и получить протяженность маршрута по данному направлению. 
Сейчас это реализовано так:

```
for(var k in result){
                var route = result[k];
                (function(route) {
                    ymaps.geocode(route.from_city, {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
                        var fromGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                        var from_point = fromGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();
                        var from_name = fromGeoObject.properties.get('name');

                        ymaps.geocode(route.to_city, {results: 1}).then(function (res) {
                            var toGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                            var to_point = toGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();
                            var to_name = toGeoObject.properties.get('name');

                            var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
                                referencePoints: points,
                                params: { results: 1 }
                            });

                            multiRoute.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function (event) {
                                try {
                                    var distance = Math.floor(multiRoute.getRoutes().get(0).properties.get('distance').value/1000);
                                }catch(err){
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                })(route)

                sleep(2000);
                console.log(route);
            }
```

В result находится массив направлений. Дело в том, что все работает через рас. То есть я получаю данные по нескольким направления, а потом начинаются выдаваться ошибки геокодирования либо ошибки при получении дистанции. Но если я прогоняю цикл еще раз, но без направлений, которые были посчитаны до этого, то направления которые в прошлый раз выдавали ошибку, считаются нормально, но опять таки только несколько (примерто 15-20). Таким образом приходиться повторять один и тот же процесс много раз, чтобы получить дистанцию по всем направлениям.

Comment: Вы пробовали выполнять функцию "геокодирования" асинхронно? Попробуйте выполнять код не синхронно, а при выполнении функции вызываит callback или возвращать promise.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Дело в том, что данные геокодирования и дистанция нужны в дальнейших расчетах, которые тоже происходят в это цикле, я просто не включил их в код, что бы не нагромождать. Там по этим данных считается стоимость маршрута. Поэтому, если все делать асинхронно, то я не смогу собрать все необходимые данные. Если я правильно понял, что Вы имеете в виду

Answer (score 2):

JS API не предназначен для решения подобных задач: фактически вы пытаетесь построить матрицу маршрутов на API, который заточен под отображение данных в вебе. Кроме того, такое использование является нарушением [условий использования сервиса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/?from=SO#conditions).

Для вашей задачи подойдет [HTTP API Маршрутизации](https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/?from=SO). Он позволяет построить и маршруты точка-точка и попарные маршруты между набором точек за один запрос.